# Why we use self here in ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm

I know methods are self bounded in ruby. I mean if we call a method without specifying the object then implicitly it takes the self object and call corresponding method.

```
require "active_record"
require 'sqlite3'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => 'test_one')

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 table_name = "account_bean" // I suck at this line
end
```

After declaring the class as specified above and querying the ActiveRecord as:

```
Account.table_name
```

I am getting "accounts" as output instead of "account_bean". But if I define Account as follows then the output is as expected.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = "account_bean" 
end
```

Can anyone clarify me why we use self here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you don't use `self`, Ruby assumes you want to set a local variable named `table_name` instead of using `table_name=` accessor (which is really `table_name=` method call).

Comment: Good but also mention, that this is called *setter method* in Ruby.. And you are actually calling the method.. +1

Comment: Even though I use table_name=("account_bean"). No luck here why ?

Comment: @Marek Lipka - Yes, even I make it as a method call, it didn't raise any error at the same time I didn't get output

Comment: @pramod The same reason. Ruby treats `table_name=('account_bean')` (which, to be honest, doesn't really differ from `table_name = 'account_bean'`) as local variable assignment.

Comment: @Marek Lipka - Thank you, got it. But can't we call super class method from subclass ? I mean by using super keyword or by using send method etc..

Comment: @pramod yes, we can, but this has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thank you, so you mean no chance here to do that

Comment: @pramod to do what? Certainly you can do what you've already done, `self.table_name = 'account_bean'` and it's the right solution for this kind of problem.